# get closest() with attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you get the closet with an attribute?

```
$('tr[data-order]:closest', $(this)).css({background:'red'});
```

I need to get the parent `tr` with attriute `data-order`

Comment: This? `$( this ).closest( 'tr[data-order]' ) `. Btw, are you saying that there are multiple TR ancestors (as in nested tables)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('theStartingObject').closest('tr[data-order]');
```

- [$.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: How is this different than what the OP posted?

Comment: @Jon Well, the OP seems to be trying to use a psuedo-selector called `closest`, which as far as I know, doesn't exist. This answer uses jQuery's `closest()` function, which does. Or am I missing somthing?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: No, that's not it.

Comment: @MattGibson: Aha! I was thinking that it *does* exist, seeing as most methods also have equivalent pseudo-selectors. You 're right (I just checked the docs), thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @clarkk Can you post your HTML, please?